# Simple Input Dialog in NSIS

Tags: applescript, nsis

In my NSIS installer, I want to display an input dialog (text + textbox) to the user and to retrieve the result of that input, so that I can use it later in the NSIS script.

I've found this reference page:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.4.15

But I couldn't find any reference to a textbox.

If it helps, what I need is the NSIS equivalent of the following AppleScript code:

```
display dialog "Insert value:" default answer ""
set value to text returned of result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) or InstallOptions (both part of NSIS) to create a custom page:

```
Outfile test.exe
Requestexecutionlevel user

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Page Custom mypagecreate mypageleave
Page Instfiles

Function mypagecreate
Var /Global MyTextbox
nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateText} 10% 20u 80% 12u "Hello World"
Pop $MyTextbox
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function mypageleave
${NSD_GetText} $MyTextbox $0
MessageBox mb_ok $0
Abort ;Don't move to next page (If the input was invalid etc)
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Popup dialogs are not really supported but it can be done with [this plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/DlgHost_plug-in)...